# How to obtain Japanese log of watson assistant

Tags: python, chatbot, ibm-watson

I executed the following code with the purpose of acquiring the log of Watson Assistant. In the acquired log, the Japanese log was garbled. 
I got a log of conversation in English. Could you tell me the response policy?

```
 #set assistant info
 import json
 from watson_developer_cloud import AssistantV1

 assistant = AssistantV1(
     version='2018-09-20',
     iam_apikey='XXXXXXX',
     url='https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/assistant/api'
 )

 # set workspace id
 workspace_id='XXXXXXXX'

 # get logs
 response = assistant.list_logs(workspace_id).get_result()
 print(json.dumps(response, indent=2))


 ###Example of acquired log (Japanese)###
 {
   "logs": [
     {
       "request": {
         "input": {
           "text": "\u3053\u3093\u306ZXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
         }
       },


 ###Example of acquired log (English)###
       "response": {
         "intents": [],
         "entities": [],
         "input": {
           "text": "hello"
         },
         "output": {
           "generic": [
           .......
```

Comment: Does the log really include "ZXXXXXXXXXX..." or did you change that? `\u3053\u3093` is perfectly correct, encoding `"こん"`, and `\u306` is missing a digit.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.

\ u306 ZXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
I changed it.
Since it was a conversation beginning with "こん" for implementation, it seems to be an encoding problem. I am looking for ways to encode when I get logs, do you know?